# POSTGRES Problems : fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, error-handling

I have seen many answers on here to "solve" this similar issue,However my  database.yml in my app is not formatted the same.

- Rails S: Works
- Rails C: Works
- **Rails db:create ->  Error: fe_sendauth:**

````
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host:  '' 
 
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: chic_development
  host: localhost
  
test:
  <<: *default
  database: chic_test 

production:
  <<: *default
  database: chic_production
  username: chic
  password: <%= ENV['CHIC_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %> ```


My Postgres App is on port 5433, not 5432. I am unsure if this is relevant. But in General I am constantly having issues with my PG being flighty. 

Please Help.
````

Comment: You have no password and user for your local database ?

Comment: Thanks.
I looked up my postgres.app and looked to see the server name and used that as username..got my password and put them in my database.yml file like this...

username: xxxxxx
password: xxxxxxxxxxx

...under the "default" block of code

then bundled everything and it worked. 
 
Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up my postgres.app and looked to see the server name and used that as username..got my password and put them in my database.yml file like this...

username: xxxxxx 
password: xxxxxxxxxxx

...under the "default" block of code then bundled everything and it worked. Thanks